# Javascript error preventing to proceed to next page

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-6

Default browser is IE in our company.  We are having issue with "Javascript Error" in IE6.

In one page there is "javascript error", Upon submitting the page (OK button), it is preventing some users to proceed to the next page.

But some users were able to proceed to the next page.

I checked IE Internet Options ... "Disable script debugging" option is selected.

Can someone please help what is causing some users not to proceed to next page.

Comment: If your company is *still* using IE6, please please please tell them to upgrade! :-(

Comment: Without any more data than that? No, probably nobody can.

Comment: We need to see the JS, and the line number throwing the error.

Comment: The only reason a company should have IE6 installed is to test applications in IE6. My sandbox install throws a javascript error on google.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Microsoft Script Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2f465be0-94fd-4569-b3c4-dffdf19ccd99) to debug JavaScript issues in IE 6 and 7. It's not a great application but it's best you can do with legacy browsers.

Comment: IE6 is company standard as of now.  Upgrading is not an option for us now.   I am wondering why it is working for some users and not to others.

Comment: Yes that's why I suggested you use the Microsoft Script Debugger, so you can debug the problem in IE6

Comment: Code wise, I know where the problem is coming from.  Problem is I am able to navigate to the next page.  But business users are unable to navigate to the next page. Is there any setting in IE side I am missing?

Comment: @user713481 IE6 itself is the problem. There is **ABSOLUTELY NO REASON** to be using IE6 **IN ANY COMPANY FOR ANY STANDARD**.

The only thing your company is doing here is LOOSING productivity. (Not to mention running into these types of errors without a good debug console).

IE6 is over **TEN years old**. I don't care if your system runs the pentagon, you could re-write that system for a modern browser, using modern standards in a fraction of the time it would take you to continually debug and support IE6.

95% of companies that still use IE6 should just declare bankruptcy immediately.

Comment: @user713481 Their lack on innovation, inability to keep up with technology and what _must be_ a general ignorance to the ideas of anyone working within their IT or DEV department (that or lack of an _intelligent_ IT/DEV department) put this company at the bottom of the food chain.

Comment: @user12121 it's impossible to tell without you posting the code but I am pretty certain it's not a setting that's causing the problem, most likely a case of bad browser mixed with bad javascript

Answer (score 0):

first of all... solve the js error 8)

well, to can help you i need to know if error is trow before the user press the submit button or after.

if it ocurs after you probably have a function thats is invoked when submit button is press, you can try to use a try { }catch block to intercept the error

if you can touch the page you can debug by hand:

using alerts
using a div

using alerts is just put a some alerts inside the code to try find where the error ocurs for examle

code1
alert(1)

code2
alert(2)

code3
alert(3)

code4
alert(4)

if you can "see" alert 3 but no alert 4 for example your error is in code 4

using div is the same way you put a  at the end of body and then

code1
document.getElementById("my_log").innerHTML("1");

code2
document.getElementById("my_log").innerHTML("2");

code3
document.getElementById("my_log").innerHTML("3");

code4
document.getElementById("my_log").innerHTML("4");

content of my_div will be a number, if it is 2 you know that the error is in code3

try this and tell us